# Single Activity with Multiple Fragments and Screen Orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen, orientation, handle

I'm currently dealing with an issue with Android & It's Re-Creation Cycle on screen rotation:

I have one single Activity and lots of Fragments (Support-V4) within. 
For example, the Login it's on a Single Activity with a Fragment, when the logs-in then the App changes it's navigation behavior and uses multiple fragments, I did this, because passing data between Fragment A to Fragment B it's way much easier than passing data Between an Activity A to an Activity B.

So My issue it's presented when I rotate the device, on my first approach, the initial fragment was loaded, but what would happen, if the user it's on Page 15 and it rotates it's device, it would return to Fragment 1 and give a very bad user-experience. I set all my fragments to retain their instance and added this on the MainActivity on Create:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    initBackStackManager();
    initControllers();
    mayDownloadData();
    setTitle();
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        addAreaFragment();
    }
}
```

Now, the first fragment is not loaded after screen orientation change, but If I try to make a fragment transaction, it says **Can not perform FragmentTransaction.commit() after onSaveInstanceState()**, is there a way to handle this? Or Do I really really need to use multiple Activities with a Fragment embedded within?

Thank you very much!

**EDITED**
I forgot to add that this happens only on a specific Fragment... For example I have the following fragment flow:

```
AreaFragment -> WaiterSelectionFragment -> WaiterOptionsFragment.
```

If I'm in the **AreaFragment** and I **rotate** the device I can still add/replace fragments and nothing happens, no error it's being thrown. If I'm on the **WaiterSelectionFragment** no error happens too. BUT, If I'm on the **WaiterOptionsFragment** the error it's being thrown. The **WaiterSelectionFragment** has the following structure:

1. LinearLayout
2. FragmentTabHost

Inside the [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html) there are some fragments, and that's where the error it's happening. You might wonder *Why FragmentTabHost?* easy, the Customer wants that App to show the TabBar, If I use Native Android Tabs the Tabs get rearranged to the **ActionBar** when on 
**Landscape** position.

**EDIT 2**

I've used the method provided by @AJ Macdonald, but no luck so far. 
I have my Current Fragment being saved at `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` method and restore my fragment on `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` method on the Android Activity, I recover my *back* button and the current ***Fragment*** but when I get to the third ***Fragment*** the error still occurs. I'm using a ***[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)*** that holds 4 Fragments, Will this be causing the Issue? Only on this section of the App Happens. I've 4 (main workflow) fragments, on the First, Second and Third Fragment no error it's being presented, only on the ***[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)*** part.

Comment: At what point are you trying to commit the transaction? Is it during an `Activity` lifecycle callback like `onPause` or `onStop`?

Comment: Nope, I have a Fragment that uses a FragmentTabHost, when the device rotates, it shows the fragment with a grid ando the user selects a cell and then, the a new fragment its added, its un that point when It uses the FragmentTransaction.commit()

Answer (score 4):

Give each of your fragments a unique tag.

In your activity's `onSaveInstanceState`, store the current fragment. (This will probably be easiest to do if you keep a variable that automatically updates every time the fragment changes.)

In your activity's `onCreate` or `onRestoreInstanceState`, pull the tag out of the saved bundle and start a new fragment of that type.

```
public static final int FRAGMENT_A = 0;
public static final int FRAGMENT_B = 1;

private int currentFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //other stuff
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        addAreaFragment();
        currentFragment = FRAGMENT_A;
    }else{
        currentFragment = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentFragment");
        switch(currentFragment){
        case FRAGMENT_A:        
        addAreaFragment();
        break;
        case FRAGMENT_B:
        addFragmentB();
        }
    }
}


// when you switch fragment A for fragment B:
currentFragment = FRAGMENT_B;


@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putInt("currentFragment", currentFragment);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: I use the class name as the fragment's tag. But... For a example, for starting Fragment B some data its passed vía a static newInstance(...) method. Also the backstack will be lost right?

Comment: If the data that you pass to Fragment B is a primitive type, you can try saving that into the savedInstanceState bundle, too. I can't think of any simple way to do it with a non-primitive object. I think the backstack will be lost when the activity is re-created. You might be able to store into the bundle an ArrayList<String> with the tags of all the backstack fragments... then, in onCreate, use that list to re-create all the fragments, replacing them in order, and adding them back onto the backstack as you go.

Comment: I'm going to try using your answer, hopefully It'll do the work... Please, see my edited post.

Comment: If you do try using an ArrayList to store the backstack tags, it would work best if you also remove tags from the list if the user hits the back button... unfortunately, I think there might not be a way to detect the back button press to make that happen. So I'm not sure how great an idea that is, overall.

Comment: That's easy, we could use the OnBackStackChangeListener to detect when a fragment it's added/removed.!

Comment: Nice! And then you should be able to use getBackStackEntryCount() to remove just the last item in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion to try is to use `FragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()` in place of `FragmentTransaction.commit()`. That should stop the Exception from being thrown, but the downside is if you rotate the device again the most recent state of the UI may not return. That is a suggestion given that I am not sure of the effect of using `FragmentTabHost`, if it has any effect at all.